# Response from a URL

Tags: java, urlconnection

I am getting a response from a URL and I am printing on the console.

The response is `Šèô;   fREïp\ô­`.

Can anyone tell me how to read this response?

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   response = response + line;
}
```

This is how I am reading a response
and the output of `System.out.println(conn.getContentType());`
is application/x-protobuffer

Comment: how are you reading it ? i dont think thats the response :O

Comment: you need to provide more detail: what technology are you using to access the URL and retrieve the server's response? what kind of reply are you expecting from the server?

Comment: @madd0 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())); String line; while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { response=response+line; } This is how i am reading a response

Comment: As an extra hint, I would like to suggest not doing string concatenation is a loop. This can be highly inefficient for non trivial input sizes.

Answer (score 3):

You mention that the MIME type of the output data is `application/x-protobuffer`.  In that case, the output you're getting is probably a [protocol buffer](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/).  Protocol buffers are a binary format, and the response you've got looks like garbage because you attempted to decode binary data as if it were text.

You may need to use Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) code to read this data.